# concrete equality of group presentations

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Why does this equality hold?
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\langle a,c|  &ca^{-1}cac^{-1}aca^{-1}c^{-1}ac^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1}c^{-1}a,\\
                &ac^{-1}aca^{-1}cac^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1}c^{-1}ac^{-1}a^{-1}c\rangle\\
=\langle a,c| &aca^{-1}cac^{-1}aca^{-1}c^{-1}ac^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1}c^{-1}\rangle\\
\end{array}$$
I'm asking this cause I don't understand the last line of this calculation:
[image]

Comment: Leon: is this more or less what you wanted?

Comment: yes, thank you. I repaired the syntax myself, but you were quicker. thanks

Comment: If I see correctly, the relation in the second group is simply obtained from the first relation in the first group by conjugating with $a$. So the question is: what is the connection between the first and the second relation in the first group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Theo remarked in the comments, the relation in the second group is obtained from the first relation in the first group by conjugating with $a$.

The second relation in the first group is obtained from the first relation in the first group by inverting it and then conjugating with $c^{-1}a$.

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: uh, you're right. this was non-trivial... thank you